# Is it possible to use AsynPipe in a *ngFor and refresh the list of Observable objects

Tags: angular, rxjs5, ngfor, angular-pipe

I have a list of objects that I get from an http GET request.

```
http.get<Array<Item>>(url)
```

I'm using the directive ***ngFor** in my template to display the items. Because I'm working directly with **Observable**, I'm using the **asyncPipe**. Like this, if I understand well, I don't have to use an intermediate list of objects and I don't have to subscribe manually to the result of the http GET request.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of itemList | async ">
```

Now, I would like to implement an automatic refresh of my list. When I get the items for the first time, if some of them are in a special state, I would like to refresh the Observable Array until all items are in the desired state.

Is it possible to do that without using an intermediate list of Items and subscribe manually ?

I tried something like that, I have almost the behavior I expect but without any refreshing of my template :

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.itemList = this.itemService.getItemList().do(items => {

    let processingItem = items.filter(item => item.status == ItemStatus.InProcess);

    if (processingItem.length > 0) {
      Observable.timer(5000).subscribe(() => this.itemList.subscribe());
    }
 });
}
```

Where getItemList() return an Observable<Array<Item>>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sequential calls of `this.itemService.getItemList()` will actually keep on reducing the list aka each time returning a new results with filtered items, then you can use the `.expand()` operator to recursively call:

```
this.itemList
    .expand(items => {
        let processingItem = items.filter(item => item.status == ItemStatus.InProcess);
        return processingItem > 0 ? this.itemService.getItemList().delay(5000) : Observable.empty();
    })
```

The above call keeps repeating calling `this.itemService.getitemList()` and delay it for 5000 ms, until the `processingItem` condition is 0. When that happens, it returns an empty `Observable`, which effectively end the stream. You do not need any manual subscribe, the `async` pipe will do the job for you.